ansible awx inventory aws ec2 groups
We have ec2 with the following tag:



key
value




roles
jboss:web



In AWX, when doing the inventory, I would like to create 2 groups:

tag_role_jboss
tag_role_web

I tried, without success, this:
keyed_groups:
  - key: "{{ tags.roles.split(':') }}"
    prefix: tag_role

I'm little bit confused about the syntax for key.
Does it accept Jinja2 syntax, or Python?
Can a key element creates multiple groups or can it create only one group?

The idea was good but not the syntax.
So, here is the correct syntax:
- key: tags.roles.split(':')


There is actually one of the examples in the documentation where they kind of hint at what is possible : - key: 'security_groups|json_query("[].group_id")', which is a Jinja expression indeed. But I'd agree that is is not very well explained, the key parameter is missing a "from jinja2 expressions", like they did in the compose one.
